# Why won't this command work in this specific code?

Tags: ruby

How would i go about this?
I tried

```
Net::HTTP.new(@site).head('/').kind_of? Net::HTTPOK
```

but I receive this:

> error: in `kind_of?': class or module required (TypeError)

I think there is something wrong with my code, can you please take a look at it? I know its very messy and pretty bad, i'm a first year programming student and i'm learning. If you have any ideas for improvement, let me know!

Also, there is something messed up with the ends contained within. For some reason i get an unexpected end error when i try to end all the defs.

Here is my code in context:

```
def begindownload
    require 'net/http'
    puts "Enter the URL of the site that you want to rip images from (use www.*website*.com/folder/file.html or other extension format):"
    while @site = gets.chomp
        puts "Querying " + @site 
        if Net::HTTP.new(@site).head('/').kind_of? Net::HTTPOK == true
            puts "Site is online!"
        else 
            puts "Site is offline. Try again."
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please post more relevant code especially the 'require' statements. Also, please help us out by formatting your question so that the code is readable.

Comment: Stackoverflow ripped the link right out! http://pastebin.com/WzSawCwz

Comment: You can format code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K (or indenting it by four spaces).

Comment: Please don't post pastebin links here (they become invalid after some time) and amend your questions with the original failing code (read: include the `if` and `== true`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you are using the line:

```
if Net::HTTP.new(@site).head('/').kind_of? Net::HTTPOK == true
```

The `==` is being evaluated first causing `Net::HTTPOK == true` to be evaluated to `false`. The rest of the statement then becomes:

```
if Net::HTTP.new(@site).head('/').kind_of? false
```

Causing your `TypeError`.

You don't need to check `== true` when you are doing an `if` statement. If the statement after the `if` evaluates to `true` then the `if` will be evaluated. Checking if a boolean `== true` is considered bad form anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .instance_of instead?